# Free up Python script-driven Selenium WebDriver's cache in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver to scrap website data 24-hour non-stop. I found out that the cache size is increasing non-stop.

```
4879M   /tmp/snap-private-tmp/snap.chromium/tmp
```

My Python script **scrap.py** is as follow:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from time import sleep

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(), options=options)

driver.get("https://example.com/")
sleep(3)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
```

This script is set to run 1000 times using this command (I know this is not a smart way):

```
for run in {1..1000}; do python scrap.py; done
```

How can I free up the disk space used after executing the Python script? Just remove the contents in the folder?

---

Currently, I am using this command to free up the cache modified more than 1 day before:

```
sudo find /tmp/snap-private-tmp/snap.chromium/tmp/ -name '.org.chromium.Chromium*' -type d -mtime +0 -exec rm -rf {} +
```

which removed 4GB data.

Comment: you can run this command using python script and you can use cron jobs to run python script 2 or 3 times in a day or may be 5 to 10 times to clean up memory, to run terminal commands using python script you can use os module or subprocess. that's what i am thinking

Comment: is it the best way to clear the cache? why do the web driver keep cache forever? did I forget to "close" or "quit" the session? I suppose the session will be closed automatically after the web scraping query.

Comment: are you forgot to close the driver if yes then quit it, i got your point. but your questions, is the best way to clear the cache? so in my opinion or my perspective we can use this way to clear the cache. or we can tell driver to free up memory.

Comment: I already use `driver.close()` at the end of my script. I will add `driver.quit()`.

Comment: ok, so now it's working or not?

Comment: It leads to high CPU usage, crashed the server. Investigating the issue still.

Comment: same issue I faced when I deployed my code, so I used driver.close() in both try and except block and it works for me

Comment: and I added Linux command `pkill -f chrome` after each long run, to ensure all Selenium sessions are gone.